# Whether a given file argument is a directory or not. C

Tags: c, directory, argv, argc

I am looking for a peace of code to check if the argument I pass to my program is a directory or not. So far I found this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat buf;

    stat(argv[1],&buf);

    exit(0);

}
```

But it does not really help me.

Comment: You should specify *why* it doesn't help you. Otherwise it doesn't help those who would like to answer you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode))
   printf(" Its a directoy\n");
else
   printf("Its a file\n");
```

after `stat(argv[1],&buf);` call